# how to disable "recent places" in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I know how to disable showing recent files, but how can I disable recent places?

[image]

Comment: which version of Word?

Comment: Microsoft Word 2010

Comment: Have you seen this? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-do-i-delete-the-recent-places-list/7e48668d-755c-47f5-9417-4f49eecd07be

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong

Comment: This link shows how to delete it. I don't wanna each time delete it manually. I wanna totally disable it.

Comment: I understand that. Unfortunately you have to wait for another answer. :-(

Comment: perhaps http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983006

Comment: The link above has a way to disable the feature using a registry change. Make a backup of your registry first, just in case.

Comment: @livingbeing am happy to help and happy it worked!  Thank you for asking this pertinent question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to disable the 'Recent Places' through the registry, provided by the Microsoft support site [Cannot change the number of places to list in Recent Places in Word 2010, in Excel 2010, or in PowerPoint 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983006).

The steps are:

> 1. Exit all Office programs.
> 2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
> 3. Locate and then click to select one of the following registry subkeys:
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Place MRU`
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Place MRU`
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Place MRU`
>
> 4. After you select the subkey that is specified in step 3, right-click
>    Max Display, and then click Modify.
> 5. Click Decimal, and in the Value data box, type a number to represent
>    the number of places that you want to list in Recent Places, and then
>    click OK.
>
> Note By default, Max Display is set to 25.
>
> 6. Repeat steps 3 through 5
>    for each Office program for which you want to change the number of
>    places that you want to list in Recent Places.
> 7. On the File menu, click
>    Exit to exit Registry Editor.

**It is absolutely critical to backup your registry first.**

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with the file extension `reg` and the following contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Place MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000
```

where `16.0` is your Word version. (If unsure about the version, run `regedit` to check which versions are listed under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\`.)

You can do that simultaneously for several Office versions, several products (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, ...), recent files (`File MRU`) and/or recent places (`Place MRU`). For example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\Place MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\File MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Place MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\File MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Place MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\File MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Place MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\File MRU]
"Max Display"=dword:00000000
```

Some products also have `User MRU`, not sure whether it can have `Max Display`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to **CLEAR the list of recent places**, this is the simplest option:

1. Click the File tab.
2. Click Recent.
3. Right click any items of the list in the Recent Places and select "Clear unpinned places".
4. Click "Yes" to clear all unpinned places from the list. Any pinned places will still appear.